# upload file with multiple input in php

Tags: php

Hello friend developers,

I have a question for upload file with multiple input in php.
This is my code for that.

```
if(isset($_FILES['images'])){


        $dateinsert = Carbon::now();
        $success = false;
        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg");
        $max_file_size = 10000000; 
        $path = 'var/www/html/test/picture/'; // Upload directory
        $count = 0;
        $folder = $path . 'picture/user' . '.' . $_SESSION["user"] . "/picture";
        $time = date("m/d/y");

        if (!file_exists($folder)) {
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
        }

        foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $f => $name) {


            if ($_FILES['images']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                $this->flash->addMessage('ErrorFile',  error');
                return; 
            }
            if ($_FILES['images']['error'][$f] == 0) {
                if ($_FILES['images']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $this->flash->addMessage('ErrorSize', 'error');
                   // error
                } elseif (!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)) {
                    $this->flash->addMessage('ErrorFormat', 'error');
                    // error
                } else { 

                    $fichier = strtr($name,
                        'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ',
                        'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');

                    $namea = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '', $fichier);
                    $namePic = explode('.', $namea);
                    $name = strtolower(uniqid(rand()) . '_' . $time . '.' . $namePic[1]);
                    $destination = $folder . "/" . $name;


                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$f], $destination))
                        $count++; 
                        $success = true;


                    if ($success === true) {



                        $stmt = $this->getDB()->prepare("INSERT INTO insert_annonce 
                                                               (img_nom,img_taille,img_type,img_desc,date_creat,id_user,id_front)
                                                               VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                        $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
                        $stmt->bindParam(2, $_FILES['images']['size'][$f]);
                        $stmt->bindParam(3, $namePic[1]);
                        $stmt->bindParam(4, $destination);
                        $stmt->bindParam(5, $dateinsert);
                        $stmt->bindParam(6, $_SESSION['user']);
                        $stmt->bindParam(7, $last_id);
                        $result = $stmt->execute();

                        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is html

```
  <input type="file" name="images[]" class="file"  data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="false" data-show-remove="false" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" data-browse-class="btn btn-blue" data-browse-label="browse"> 
  <input type="file" name="images[]" class="file"  data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="false" data-show-remove="false" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" data-browse-class="btn btn-blue" data-browse-label="browse"> 
  <input type="file" name="images[]" class="file"  data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="false" data-show-remove="false" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" data-browse-class="btn btn-blue" data-browse-label="browse"> 
  <input type="file" name="images[]" class="file"  data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="false" data-show-remove="false" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" data-browse-class="btn btn-blue" data-browse-label="browse">
```

The script works but it loads me a single file and not the others in my database.

Thank you in advance for the explanations

Comment: What output did you get when you debug `$_FILES['images']` = `print_r('<pre>'); var_dump($_FILES['images']); exit;`

Comment: you have a typo, already seen by the code highlighter in your post, `('ErrorFile',  error');`

Comment: Of course, I debugged before posting the message. On exit I have my 4 files with their properties. @ghost => This is not a typical error, it is a copied paste error.

Comment: OK it's good Thank !!!!